# No Grub on VPS?

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, grub, virtuozzo

I bought a new VPS running CentOS 5.5, and I'm trying to upgrade my kernel. I've downloaded, compiled and installed it sucessfully, and now I need to set it up in the grub settings. But there's no `grub` directory in `/boot`.

Where is, then, the `/boot/grub/menu.lst` or `grub.conf` file?

**Edit:** When I do `rpm -ql grub` it throws `package grub is not installed`. How can I know the boot loader and change its settings?

```
[root@server css]# find /boot -exec rpm -qf {} \;
filesystem-2.4.0-3.el5
file /boot/System.map-2.6.33.5-rt23.old is not owned by any package
file /boot/System.map-2.6.33.5-rt23 is not owned by any package
redhat-logos-4.9.99-11.el5.centos
file /boot/System.map is not owned by any package
file /boot/vmlinuz is not owned by any package
file /boot/grub is not owned by any package
redhat-logos-4.9.99-11.el5.centos
file /boot/initrd-2.6.33.5-rt23.img is not owned by any package
file /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.33.5-rt23 is not owned by any package
file /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.33.5-rt23.old is not owned by any package

[root@server css]# rpm -ql lilo
package lilo is not installed

[root@server css]# head -c 5000 /dev/xvda | strings
head: cannot open `/dev/xvda' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Virtuozzo, you don't get the ability to choose your own kernel. If you need this functionality, you'll need to choose a Xen-based VPS provider that allows users to provide their own kernel. I know that [Linode](http://www.linode.com/) allows this via [pv-grub](http://library.linode.com/advanced/pv-grub-howto), and I'm sure there are others that allow this as well.

Comment: I'd be remiss if I didn't mention that BlackMesh allows it (and will even custom-compile and install the kernel *for you*!) on their Xen VPS's, as well as on their dedicated boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
rpm -ql grub
```

On a separate note: is there a reason you aren't using the stock kernel?  Unless you have a compelling need for new features that haven't been backported, compiling your own kernel is somewhere between foolhardy and suicidal.

As you've now updated your OP: perhaps you're using LILO?

```
rpm -ql lilo
```

Okay, how about:

```
head -c 5000 /dev/xvda | strings
```

Okay, it might not be named /dev/xvda exactly; take a look at the output of:

```
df
```

and grab the first bits (the part before the number(s)) for your root filesystem.

Comment: df returns `/dev/vzfs`. I tried `head -c 5000 /dev/vzfs | strings` and still no such file or directory.

Comment: Ah, that's Virtuozzo, then.  I don't work with that, but I've added it to the tags, so hopefully someone can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help anyway :) I've learnt some things on kernels :) (sorry for english)

Answer (score 1):

On OpenVZ containers or Virtuozzo containers there is no kernel and there is no way to ever have a kernel.

The virtual machine is basically a chroot jail for the processes, whatever the host is using for a kernel is what your machine is powered by.   Jails are great for extreme and very good reliability.

If you need a VPS that has a custom kernel you will need to run some sort of full virtualization like Xen-HVM or Linux KVM, or even VMWare.

Xen Para will offer limited ability to customize your kernel.